# Question in Past tense vs. Question in Passive

Tags: past-tense, passive-voice

I was reading about **Passive** in the book "Essential Grammar in use" by Raymond Murphy,

In page no.52 , I found an example that confused me,

> '**Was anybody injured** in the accident?'
>   'Yes, two people were taken to the hospital.'

The question can also be like the below example with Past tense, right?

> '**Did anybody get injured** in the accident?'

Is there any difference in meaning between the above two examples?

Which one is more common?

Please clarify. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was anybody injured in the accident?

Did anybody get injured in the accident?

Both are correct and convey the same meaning.  However, the former sentence is an example of standard passive formed with be + past participle.  The latter get passive is usually used in informal speaking.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also please clarify this, Which one is formal & informal speaking in the below example? "Did you get injured?" & "Were you got injured?"

Comment: The first is infornal, and the second is incorrect.  You should say: Were you injured?